# Set macro in xcode

Tags: xcode, macros

I created a new xcode project and put in the source files of the clunk library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/clunk/). When I try to build that project I get the following error:

```
error turn on SSE support with CLUNK_USES_SSE macro
```

How can I set that macro to... i don't know.. true in xcode??? Or what value do it need?

Comment: I guess it's something you don't control but clunk should set those for you. Have you tried googling something similar? Check this link : http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2983651&group_id=241929&atid=1117499

Answer (score 0):

Add the macro to the Preprocessor Macros build setting. I have not used Clunk, but adding CLUNK_USES_SSE to the Preprocessor Macros build setting should set the macro to true.